# How to add image file to setup in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I have made a setup for my C# application but when i installed it on another computer, it showed me an error that Path contains illegal characters. I used the following code to load the logo into picturebox .

```
            PictureBox.Load("|DataDirectory|\\CLogo.jpg");
```

Comment: try this PictureBox.Load(@"|DataDirectory|\\CLogo.jpg");

Comment: If your logo is static you'd be better off putting it into a resource file and compiling it with your project instead of loading it externally.

Comment: Does the path on the "other" computer contains Arabic characters?